# Found non-callable @@iterator when extending Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, extends

When i try extend the Array class:

```
class Collection extends Array {
    constructor(array){
        super(...array)
    }

    getTimes(){
        return this.map(value=> value.getTime())
    }

    min(){
        return new Date(Math.min(...this.getTimes()))
    }
}



const array = ['2000/02/01','2000/02/02']
const dates = array.map(value => new Date(value))

const test = new Collection(dates)

console.log(test[Symbol.iterator]); //Iterator exists
console.log(test.min()); ///Error: Found non-callable @@iterator
```

For some reason a get this error, but when we do this:

```
class Collection extends Array {
    static from(array){ /// Using a Factory instead of a constructor
        return new Collection(...array)
    }
...
...
}

const test = Collection.from(dates)

console.log(test.min()); //returns the Date
```

Everything works fine. Why does the constructor is having problem with iterators??

Comment: Are you sure `.from()` is working? I'm still facing issues with the `.from()` approach: https://jsfiddle.net/3p6y81dc/

Comment: @NickParsons I was able to get the Array.from() to work. You've got the order of things switched up. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/9eqwg1nd/

Comment: @ScottyJamison ah yes, good one, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that array.map() returns a *new* array, and will call your constructor in order to do so.

This behavior can be seen here:

```js
class CustomArray extends Array {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
    console.log('constructor called')
  }
}

const myArray = new CustomArray(1, 2, 3)
console.log('call .map()')
myArray.map(x => x)
```

Because your custom constructor doesn't take the same parameters as the default array constructor, the .map() function trips up when it attempts to use it. The following implementation will work for you, because it changes the constructor to take the arguments that .map() expects.

```js
class Collection extends Array {
    constructor(...args){
        super(...args)
    }

    getTimes(){
        return this.map(value=> value.getTime())
    }

    min(){
        return new Date(Math.min(...this.getTimes()))
    }
}



const array = ['2000/02/01','2000/02/02']
const dates = array.map(value => new Date(value))

const test = new Collection(...dates)

console.log(test.min());
```

Maybe this isn't what you want though, because maybe you want to change the behavior of the constructor. Turns out, Javascript provides a special [species symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@species) for arrays, specifically to help with making array subclasses like you're doing. You can give this species symbol a different constructor to use, and functions such as `.map()` will use whatever is provided by this species symbol instead.

```js
class Collection extends Array {
    constructor(array){
        super(...array)
    }
    
    static [Symbol.species](...args) {
        return new Collection(args)
    }

    static get [Symbol.species]() {
      return function(...args) {
        return new Collection(args)
      }
    }

    getTimes(){
        return this.map(value=> value.getTime())
    }

    min(){
        return new Date(Math.min(...this.getTimes()))
    }
}



const array = ['2000/02/01','2000/02/02']
const dates = array.map(value => new Date(value))

const test = new Collection(dates)

console.log(test.min());
```

This is using a number of tricks, so I would recommend avoiding this specific solution if possible. But, the basic idea is that the species property should be set to a class, that will then be newed by functions such as .map(). In the above example, I made the `species` property a getter (I couldn't get it to work properly otherwise - I think it has something to do with how it's default value is set). This getter returned a function, that will act like a class in this scenario (you don't have to use the class keyword to make a class). When a normal function is newed, I just return an instance of the Collection class, properly constructed (even though this anonymous function is the thing being constructed, it can return something completely different).